# Where are the MS Access tables I have shortcuts to?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a MS Access 2013 file that I am using.  There are two possibly related concerns.  For some context, this is an MS Access 2013 file with some forms and some tables and a bit of VBA for the logic of how those two interact.  For versioning, the file has been copied and pasted with a datestamp on it for the newer version.

The first concern is that all the file sizes for the various files is exactly the same, even though data has been added and some changes to the forms were made.

The second concern is that when I right click on a table and go to table properties, it says "Shortcut to Table (Local): table_name"  where table_name is the name of the table.  It appears that this is a shortcut to a table somewhere, but I'm not sure where.  The forms are also shortcuts to forms, but I don't see the destination form in my file anywhere, even after unhiding system objects.  My questions regarding this are: how did this happen (I was assuming it had something to do with the fact that I copied and pasted the file) and where is the file that these are a shortcut to?

Everything seems to work fine, but I'm concerned that if one of the legacy files gets removed that I might lose some data.  Is my data being stored within this file, or did it get split somehow and the data is being stored in a different file somewhere?  I just want to have a better grasp of what exactly is going on.

I feel like I have a good handle on the SQL and a pretty good grasp of the VBA, but the MS Access specific nuances are something I'm still gaining familiarity with.

Comment: tldr but, is your navigation pane set to "Custom" view?

Comment: Jens, my navigation pane was set to Custom - changing it resolves the "Shortcut" issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems it was as simple as changing the view in your navigation pane to something else than [custom!](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-manage-custom-categories-and-groups-in-the-Navigation-Pane-ccfb0ee7-d72f-4923-b4fb-ed6c15484244?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)